# Why does my c++ object gets deleted as soon as i create it?

Tags: c++, object

I have created a class to make it possible to render multiple objects on the screen, which i called "Entity", here is the code for the 3 constructors:

```
Entity::Entity()
{
    x = y = z = 0;
    std::cout<<"INIT MODEL"<<std::endl;
    model = Model();
    model.loadModel2("huis_0.txt");
} 
Entity::Entity(float xVal,float yVal,float zVal,std::string source)
{
    std::cout<<"INIT MODEL2"<<std::endl;
    x = xVal;
    y = yVal;
    z = zVal;
    model = Model();
    model.loadModel2(source);
}
Entity::Entity(std::string source)
{
    x = y = z = 0;
    std::cout<<"INIT MODEL3"<<std::endl;
    model = Model();
    model.loadModel2(source);
}
```

The deconstructor simple prints out "deleting entity".
Then i load an entity in my main file using the second method.
Model is another class that simply loads the vertices and indices from a file.
During the run this is the output i get:

```
INIT2
++loading model+++
++done loading model++
deleting entity
//other prints
deleting entity
```

then after i close my window. i get the following error: "debug failed: expression:_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) "
My guess is i get this error because i delete the object twice. How do i prevent this?
That is also the only entity i have so that can't be it.

EDIT: The Entity object gets created outside any method, at the top of my main file because i wanted to use the Entity's "render()" method.

EDIT2: This are all the functions where sword is used, please excuse me for it being messy, i was trying out the openGL codes i learned:

```
Entity sword = Entity(0,0,0,"pirate_sword.txt");

void Initialize(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    InitWindow(argc, argv);

    fprintf(stdout,"INFO: OpenGL Version: %s\n",glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    //model.loadModel2("huis_0.txt");
    model.loadModel2("test_zwaard_0.txt");

    glGenVertexArrays(1,&vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    ShaderLoader loader;
    std::string test = loader.loadStringFromFile("vertex_shader.txt");
    std::string frag = loader.loadStringFromFile("fragment_shader.txt");
    program = loader.loadProgram(GL_VERTEX_SHADER,test,GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,frag);
    glUseProgram(program);

    /*LIGHTING*/
    ambient_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program,"ambient");
    lightColor_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program,"lightColor");
    lightDirection_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program,"lightDirection");
    halfVector_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program,"halfVector");
    shiny_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program,"shiny");
    strength_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program,"strength");
    GLfloat ambient[3] = {
        0.4,0.4,0.4
    };
    glUniform3f(ambient_loc,ambient[0],ambient[1],ambient[2]);
    GLfloat lightColor[3] = {
        0.4,0.4,0.4
    };
    glUniform3f(lightColor_loc,lightColor[0],lightColor[1],lightColor[2]);
    GLfloat lightDirection[3] = {
        1.0,0.2,0.4
    };
    glUniform3f(lightDirection_loc,lightDirection[0],lightDirection[1],lightDirection[2]);
    GLfloat halfVector[3] = {
        1.0,0.2,0.4
    };
    glUniform3f(halfVector_loc,halfVector[0],halfVector[1],halfVector[2]);
    float shiny = 0.2f;
    glUniform1f(shiny_loc,shiny);
    float strength = 0.7f;
    glUniform1f(strength_loc,strength);

    /*END OF LIGHTING*/
    /*TRANSFORM*/
    persp_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program,"persp");
    model_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program,"model");
    camera_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program,"camera");

    glm::mat4 transform_model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f));
        glm::rotate(transform_model,20.0f,glm::vec3(x,y,z));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(model_loc,16,false,&transform_model[0][0]);
    glm::mat4 transform_camera = (glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(3,5,-5),glm::vec3(0,0,0),glm::vec3(0,1,0)));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(camera_loc,16,false,&transform_camera[0][0]);
    glm::mat4 transform_persp = glm::perspective(45.0f,float(4/3),(float)0.5,(float)100);

    //Matrix4 m;
    //m.translateMatrix(0.2f,0.0f,0.0f);
    float frustumScale = 1.0f,zNear = 0.1f,zFar = 100.0f;
    GLfloat persp[16];
    memset(persp,0.0f,sizeof(persp));
    persp[0] = frustumScale;
    persp[5] = frustumScale;
    persp[10] = (zFar + zNear) / (zNear - zFar);
    persp[14] = (2 * zFar * zNear) / (zNear - zFar);
    persp[11] = -1.0f;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(persp_loc,16,false,&transform_persp[0][0]);
    glUseProgram(0);

    glGenBuffers(1,&vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
    GLfloat model_test[834]; //834
    memset(model_test,0.0f,sizeof(model_test));
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<834;i++) model_test[i] = model.getIndex(i);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(model_test),&model_test,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    GLuint ibo;
    glGenBuffers(1,&ibo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,ibo);
    GLshort indices[1656];//1656
    memset(indices,0,sizeof(indices));
    for(int i=0;i<1656;i++) indices[i] = model.getVertexIndex(i);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(indices),&indices,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    getGLerrors("init");

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    getGLerrors("depth");

    sword.init();
    sword.move(0.3f,0.0f,0.0f);

    getGLerrors("sword init");
}
void RenderFunction(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(program);
        glm::mat4 transform_model = glm::mat4(0.5f);
        glm::rotate(transform_model,20.0f,glm::vec3(x,y,z));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(model_loc,16,false,&transform_model[0][0]);
    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,model.getSize()/3);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    if(rasterize)glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);
    else glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_FILL);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,model.getIndexSize(),GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(model_loc,16,false,&sword.getTransform()[0][0]);
    sword.render();

    getGLerrors("draw");

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: You should use a constructor initialization list instead of assigning to things in the body.

Comment: We'd need to see the code that creates Entity to answer your question.

Comment: @Tim the code is really simple: Entity sword = Entity(0,0,0,"sword.txt");

Comment: @AntonD Tim meant the relevant parts from the scope where this is happening, not just the constructor call line.

Comment: It would be really nice if even ***one*** of the debugging output messages you have in the code were actually in the accompanying output listing (or vise-versa). Methinks it would make it considerably easier to understand when viewed side-by-side with the code that is actually *creating* these things.

Comment: @WhozCraig I didn't add it because my project has multiple files and it would be too much to read.

Comment: Whoa. its a *global*? (I originally suspected it was local-to-main and passed out, but clearly that isn't happening).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure how you're creating `Entity`, but this is creating a temporary `Model`, copying into `model`, and then destroying the temporary:

```
model = Model();
```

I bet you're doing something similar with `Entity`.

Comment: This is how i created it: Entity sword = Entity(0,0,0,"sword.txt"); so i never created something empty.

Comment: @AntonD But to you ever pass it to any functions? By any, I mean ***any whatsoever***? I ask because reference parameters, judging by your constructor `source` parameter, do not seem to be your forte`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes i did, in the init method of the file i called sword.init() and sword.render() but i also called this openGL function: glUniformMatrix4fv(model_loc,16,false,&house.getTransform()[0][0]); Am i creating a new object when called this?

Comment: @AntonD Not quite where I was going. Do you ever *pass* `sword` to any functions *at all*?

Comment: @AntonD: I didn't say you created something empty. I said you created something *temporary*. You're creating a temporary `Entity`, using that to create `sword` via the copy constructor, and then the temporary is destroyed.

Comment: @WhozCraig No i don't, do you want me to add the main.cpp file?

Comment: @AntonD That would likely be helpful. At least the `main()` function and all its glory.

Comment: Maybe what you really want is `Entity sword(0, 0, 0, "sword.txt");`.

Comment: @FredLarson I would have though the temp-copy would be elided out, or so [i'm lead to believe](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). Are you saying it *shouldn't* be in this case? If so, why so (I'm genuinely curious). Implementation dependency?

Comment: @WhozCraig: It could be elided, you're right. It wouldn't have to be, though.

Comment: @FredLarson It *should* be, but isn't copy-elision impilementation-dependent? I honestly can't remember, but I suspect it ... is? (the kind of statement that some serious reps can turn around and open a can of whoop-ass with, so I tread gingerly).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Well, as your link says, "... compilers are *permitted* to omit the copy- and move-constructors ..." (emphasis mine). It doesn't say they're required to.

Comment: @FredLarson Yes, thank you this was what i needed i don't get that message anymore! How do i accept a reply to a reply as an answer?

Comment: @AntonD: There may be a waiting period, but you should see a hollow outline of a checkmark under the votes box. Click that when you see it.

Comment: @AntonD Glad you found a solution. Fred, interesting twist. I wonder if it being global had anything to do with it. Good conv. Take care. (and +1 on the answer, I was auto-copy-eliding and never considered it possibly wasn't being done).

Comment: @FredLarson One last question, I'm coming from Java and whitin Java it is common to do Entity entity; and then init it later, how do i achieve the same thing in c++? Or should i initialize global objects right away?

Comment: @AntonD: First of all, using globals is a questionable practice in general. Second, if you do use global objects, you can run into [issues with static initialization](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html) in some circumstances. If you need to defer instantiation, you'll probably need to use pointers (preferably smart pointers) and dynamic allocation.